# Run existing Laravel project with sail

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-8, laravel-sail, laravel-9

I have an existing Laravel project which I created with the [following command](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#getting-started-on-linux).

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

The project was created successfully and when I start it with command `./vendor/bin/sail up` it works fine.

I want to clone the project on my second machine and start with sail. I found the [following link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects) from documentation which gives you possibility to run `composer install` even if you don't have composer installed on your OS.

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

This basically starts a docker container which has php and composer installed and runs `composer install`.

Installing packages work fine, but whenever I run `./vendor/bin/sail up` then it throws errors and the application is not started.

[image]
It looks like some packages were not installed.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you should update `laravel/sail` package first and then run composer install.

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer update laravel/sail
```

---

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```